# 大量の画像ファイルを読み込む時、読み込み速度が次第に遅くなる

Tags: vb.net, winforms

あるフォルダに縦80ピクセル、横100ピクセルにリサイズされた4000枚の画像ファイルが置いてあります。これを読み込んでListViewコントロールに画像の一覧を表示します。

問題は時間がかかる事です。読み込み処理の時、最初の1000枚は約30秒かかるのですが、次の1000枚は約56秒、次の1000枚は約79秒、次の1000枚は約105秒かかります。だんだんと読み込み速度が遅くなってるようなのです。これを最初の読み込み速度を維持したまま全部読み込めば、約２分で全部読み込み終わります。

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Dim imgList As New ImageList
  Dim sec As Double = 0

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Dim oldsec As Integer = 0

    For Each path As Object In Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath & "\cache\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
      imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(fs, False, False))

      ListView1.Items.Add(path, imgList.Images.Count)

      If imgList.Images.Count = 1000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("1 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 2000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("2 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 3000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("3 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 4000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("4 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      End If
    Next

    sw.Stop()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    imgList.ImageSize = New Size(100, 80)
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imgList
  End Sub
```

出力ウィンドウに出力された文字列

```
1 sec = 31.8310536  diff = 31.8310804
2 sec = 88.7196354  diff = 56.7196397
3 sec = 168.8318207  diff = 79.831824
4 sec = 274.2561862  diff = 105.256191
```

どのようにすれば最初の読み込み速度を維持したまま全部読み込み終えるでしょうか？あるいはもっと早く読み込み終えられるでしょうか？
条件としては、ListViewの仮想モードを使わない、基本的にはマルチスレッドを使わない、です。

Comment: ImageListを使わない方法があるようですので試してみては？ [ImageListにImageを追加するのが遅い（ListView+ImageList）](https://dobon.net/vb/bbs/log3-35/21547.html), [ImageListで大量イメージを扱う際のパフォーマンス劣化](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=63353&KLOG=106)

Comment: おそらく遅いのは、読み込みじゃなくてImageListやListViewへの追加ですよね。まずはそこちゃんと切り分けたほうが良いんじゃないかと。ImageListへの追加は遅くないなら、ListViewへは最後に１回で追加するとか方法があるかもしれませんし

Comment: kunif様＜教えていただいたリンク先を見た所、OwnerDrawを使っているようですが、OwnerDrawは仮想モードの事だと思いますが、仮想モードを使うと確かにすぐに読み込めるのですが、ListViewのスクロール処理が若干もたつきますし、仮想モードはすでに別の所で使っているので今回は知りたい情報ではないです。

Comment: user15092様＜アドバイスに従ってListViewへの追加を最後らへんでまとめて行ったところかなり速度が改善されました。その事を追記で質問欄に書きました。貴重なアドバイスをありがとうございます。

Comment: OwnerDrawと仮想モードは違うものと思われます [ListView の仮想リストビューを用いる - VirtualListView, VirtualMode の利用 (C#プログラミング)](https://www.ipentec.com/document/csharp-listview-using-virtual-listview), [ListView(.Net)を仮想モードで高速化する](https://qiita.com/zunda_pixel/items/368efcc8987fc9d4f567), [ListViewの仮想表示モード その１](https://satox.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20080601/1212285517) が、目的が達成されたなら良いことですね。

Comment: ここは一問一答形式のQAです。最初の2分で読み込み終わりたいという課題が解決したのであれば一旦完了として、新たな質問は新規に質問を起こしてください

Comment: keitaro_so様＜了解しました。質問欄を編集して自己回答を追加しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

処理の開始時に[`ListView.BeginUpdate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)、終了後に[`ListView.EndUpdate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を呼ぶことで、項目操作毎の画面更新を抑止できるため、処理を高速化できます。

---

ただし、`ListView.BeginUpdate()`の項目でも説明されていますが、[`ListView.AddRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.addrange?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)を使用した方が効果的です。しかも`ImageList`側には`BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate`が存在せず[`AddRange()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.addrange?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)のみですのでなおさらです。

C#でしか書けないのですが次のような流れになります。

```cs
var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

var images = new List<Image>();
var items = new List<ListViewItem>();

foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "/cache")) {
    var fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    images.Add(Image.FromStream(fs, false, false));
    items.Add(new ListViewItem(path, images.Count));
}

imgList.Images.AddRange(images.ToArray());
ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());

Debug.WriteLine("sec = {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。正しいかは分かりませんが、VBで書き直したコードを僕の回答欄に追記しました。sayuri様のコードでさらに早く処理する事ができました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントして頂いた方のアドバイスに従ってListViewへの追加を最後らへんに行うようにしたところ、かなり早くなりました。

出力ウィンドウに出力された文字列

```
1 sec = 1.7978672  diff = 1.7978888
2 sec = 4.0005821  diff = 2.0005857
3 sec = 6.5848129  diff = 2.5848188
4 sec = 9.9223631  diff = 2.9223676
sec = 32.1548404  diff = 22.1548443
```

変更後のコード

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Dim imgList As New ImageList
  Dim sec As Double = 0
  Dim strArr(4001) As String

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Dim oldsec As Integer = 0
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    For Each path As Object In Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath & "\cache\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
      imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(fs, False, False))

      strArr(index) = path
      index += 1

      If imgList.Images.Count = 1000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("1 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 2000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("2 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 3000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("3 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      ElseIf imgList.Images.Count = 4000 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("4 sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
        oldsec = Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
      End If
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To 3999
      ListView1.Items.Add(strArr(i), i)
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString & "  diff = " & Math.Abs(oldsec - Double.Parse(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)))
    sw.Stop()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    imgList.ImageSize = New Size(100, 80)
    ListView1.LargeImageList = imgList
  End Sub
```

ありがとうございました。

**--------------------------追記---------------------------**

sayuri様の回答を参考に試してみたらさらに少し早くなりました。

出力ウィンドウに出力された文字列

```
sec = 1.0324989
sec = 10.7114742
sec = 17.5112929
```

コード

```vb
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()

    Dim images As New List(Of Image)
    Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

    For Each path In Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath & "\cache\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
      Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(path)
      images.Add(Image.FromStream(fs, False, False))
      items.Add(New ListViewItem(path, images.Count))
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine("sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
    imgList.Images.AddRange(images.ToArray())

    Debug.WriteLine("sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString)
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray())

    Debug.WriteLine("sec = " & sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString) 
    sw.Stop()
  End Sub
```

ListView.ListViewItemCollection.AddRangeの使い方などを教えていただきありがとうございました。